# invalid syntax (<string>, line 4) (syntax-error)

Tags: python, pylint

I have an invalid syntax according to flake8, pylint, but the code works.
What's wrong with that code?

I did lots of Google search but couldn't find anything.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open("test.py", "a") as output:
    # E:  4, 0: invalid syntax (<string>, line 4) (syntax-error)
    print("hello world", file=output)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the linters for 3 and not those for 2? Under 2, due to the print statement,  it is an error for the same reason that `(1, a=2)` is an error because tuples cannot have key value pairs. Only argument lists can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Python are you running? I'm not sure when it was implemented exactly but I don't think earlier versions of Python had a file=output parameter for the print() function so your interpreter might only be expecting a string

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.15

Comment: Ah ok, well I think that's the problem - after some googling, it seems like there are two ways to handle it: 

1) If you have access, use `from __future__ import print_function` which allows you to use the print() function from Python 3.x in your Python 2.7 code, or: 

2) Apparently this would also write to a file, though I don't have Python 2.7 installed so I can't verify: `print >>output, 'This is a test'` (replace the 'this is a test' with your text)